# Dropwizard precreated SSL certificate

Tags: dropwizard

I have 2 ssl files -> crtificate.pem, unencryptedkey.pem

How can I condig Dropwizrad with it's embedded jetty to work in SSL?

Thanks.
Id

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [documentation](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/core.html#ssl), you set it up using the configuration yaml file.

```
server:
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: https
      port: 8443
      keyStorePath: example.keystore
      keyStorePassword: example
      validateCerts: false
```

However, as the [configuration reference](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/configuration.html#https) mentions, you can only use `JKS, PKCS12, JCEKS, Windows-MY, or Windows-ROOT`; **not PEM**. So you either create `JKS` (not sure about JCEKS) using java `keytool`

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias <your alias> -file <your file>.pem -keystore <your key store>.jks -storepass <your storepass>
```

or PKCS12 using `openssl`

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in file.pem -out file.p12 -name "My Certificate"
```

or [import it to your Windows Certificate Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/import-export-certificates-private-keys#1TC=windows-7).